# AWS Cognito Multiple SAML Providers

Tags: amazon-cognito

I can't seem to get a straight answer from SO, the internet, or AWS docs regarding support for multiple SAML (or OIDC) IdP in AWS Cognito.

We have a situation where we may need to have multiple IdP in use with SAML on a single Cognito instance. If this is a problem the project needs to know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cognito can handle multiple SAML providers quite easily. When the user logs in they will have to choose which SAML provider, and their user will only be associated with that provider (not multiple).

In the Cognito user pool console go to Federation -> Identity Providers -> SAML
There you can add each provider.

If you use the Cognito hosted UI for login, selecting between multiple IDPs is all handled. If you are building a custom UI, you will need to make sure you handle that logic.

[image: Cognito SAML provider config in console]

Comment: "and their user will only be associated with that provider (not multiple)." 
What happens if you have the same email user across different providers?

Comment: Not a problem, when the user logs in, they have to select which provider they want to use. So if you have multiple providers and the same user in both, they just pick which one they want to use. However, they will be two different Cognito users.